# Filter out records using 2 collection through Java streams

Tags: arraylist, collections, java-8, set, java-stream

I have an Customer type

```
class Customer{
    String custName;
    String custCity;
    //getter & setter
}

Set<Customer> custSet = new HashSet<>(); //populated with few records

class City{
    Integer cityId;
    String cityName;
    //getter & setter
}
List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>(); //populated with few records
```

I want to select those records from custSet where custCity does not matches with any record from cityList.

```
cityList [{cityId=1, cityName=NewYork},{cityId=2, cityName=Chicago}]
custSet [{custName=John, custCity=NewYork},{custName=Jill, custCity=Delhi}]
```

//record {custName=Jill, custCity=Delhi} should get selected & saved in new Set because custCity=Delhi is not present in cityList. How to do this?

I tried below:

```
cityList.stream()
   .map(City::getCityName)
   .anyMatch(
     custSet.stream()
       .map(Customer::getCustCity)
       .collect(toSet())
       ::contains)
```

But the above doesn't return a set where record {custName=John, custCity=NewYork} is removed. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what do you really need. What is the expected output? You want to select records from `custSet` but your code is filtering on `cityList`.

Comment: my expected output is {custName=Jill, custCity=Delhi} because Delhi is not present in cityList

Comment: If I'm right cityId is a number type (e.g. Integer), not String. It is defined as String property, but the sample output shows Integers.

Comment: corrected data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method you can use in your scenario is noneMatch, following is the code snippet that might help in your context:

```
        Set<Customer> filteredCustomer = custSet
                .stream()
                .filter(customer ->
                        cityList
                                .stream()
                                .noneMatch(city -> customer.getCustCity().equals(city.getCityName())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```